# Push notification and Cyrillic characters

Tags: iphone, push-notification

I used php script from tutorial

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = '********';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = '******';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'problem message';


$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'NewCk.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
 $fp = stream_socket_client(
'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
'badge' => 1,
'alert' => $message,
'sound' => 'default'
);

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

 // Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

and i get the problem with message of this push notification. When I send message with latin characters everything is fine, but when I try to send russian message, on my IPhone I get "?????" instead of characters. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Might want to try utf8_encode on the value of $message, i.e. 

`$message = utf8_encode( '<the problem message>' );`

Comment: I get the result - instead of "????" i got unreadable symbols.

Comment: I just managed to send an push notification without any changes (besides the obvious ones [token, passphrase]) to the code above. The only thing that I had to watch is that the PHP file is saved in `UTF-8` format (not `UTF-16` or anything else).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use it by browser, just add header in HTML, for example:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

or in php

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: This is just for the results of the php script. NOT the push notification sent to a device

Comment: Thanks, this header helped perfectly